# Quantifier-free way to specify constructor of Z3 sum type

Tags: z3, smt

Let's say I have a simple sum type in Z3 with several constructors of different arities:

```
(declare-datatypes ()
  ((Foo bar
        (baz (unbaz String))
        (quux (unquux1 String) (unquux2 Int)))))
```

How can I assert that I know value of type `Foo` is a `quux`? I could introduce an existential over `quux1` and `quux2` but I'm wary of introducing seemingly unnecessary quantifiers. Is there a better way to assert this?

Answer (score 1):

Existentials are rather harmless when assumed because the existentially quantified variables are directly instantiated and thus only entail additional symbols. That is, the second half of the snippet

```
(declare-datatypes ()
  ((Foo bar
        (baz (unbaz String))
        (quux (unquux1 String) (unquux2 Int)))))

(declare-const f Foo)

(assert (exists ((s String) (i Int)) ;; Let f be a quux
  (= f (quux s i))
))

(assert (= f (baz "test"))) ;; Also let f be a baz
(check-sat) ;; UNSAT - as expected
```

is equivalent to

```
...
(declare-const _s String)
(declare-const _i Int)
(assert (= f (quux _s _i))) ;; Let f be a quux

(assert (= f (baz "test"))) ;; Also let f be a baz
(check-sat) ;; UNSAT - as expected
```

If you're wary of existentials but not of foralls, then you could *tag* `Foo` values by axiomatising a mapping from `Foo` constructors to distinct tags:

```
(set-option :smt.mbqi false)

(declare-datatypes ()
  ((Foo bar
        (baz (unbaz String))
        (quux (unquux1 String) (unquux2 Int)))))

;; Declare a finite sort Foo_tag with three distinct elements
(declare-datatypes () ((Foo_tag Foo_tag.bar Foo_tag.baz Foo_tag.quux)))

;; Alternatively, three distinct elements from an infinite sort such 
;; as Int can be used. Either by choosing distinct but unspecified 
;; values, as done below, or by directly choosing concrete values,
;; e.g. 1, 2, 3.
; (define-sort Foo_tag () Int)
; (declare-const Foo_tag.bar Foo_tag)
; (declare-const Foo_tag.baz Foo_tag)
; (declare-const Foo_tag.quux Foo_tag)
; (assert (distinct Foo_tag.bar Foo_tag.baz Foo_tag.quux))

;; Tagging function
(declare-fun tag_of (Foo) Foo_tag)

;; Tagging axiom for bar ...
(assert (= (tag_of bar) Foo_tag.bar))

;; ... baz ...
(assert (forall ((s String)) (! 
  (= (tag_of (baz s)) Foo_tag.baz)
  :pattern ((baz s))
)))

;; ... and quux
(assert (forall ((s String) (i Int)) (! 
  (= (tag_of (quux s i)) Foo_tag.quux)
  :pattern ((quux s i))
)))

;; Let's do some testing

(declare-const f Foo)

(assert (= (tag_of f) Foo_tag.quux)) ;; Tag f as a quux

(push)
  (assert (= f bar))
  (check-sat) ;; UNSAT - as expected
(pop)

(push)
  (assert (= f (baz "test")))
  (check-sat) ;; UNSAT - as expected
(pop)
```

Comment: The "forall" approach would be impossible if the type was parametrized, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not impossible, but definitely more complicated: If you have finitely many types, you can instantiate the "forall" approach once per type, similar to how C++-style templates are instantiated. Otherwise, you might have to encode types as terms, which is how Boogie (https://github.com/boogie-org/boogie) encodes quantifications over types.